# PC connected to SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: database, connection, sql-server-2012

I found the query `exec sp_who2` to find who is connected to the database server. But it tells me the log in name, I need to know the pc name that is connected??

I used to use activity monitor in SQL Server 2005 but that also gives the login name

Comment: Do you need to do this programatically or is a manual approach acceptable? Please be as specific as possible when writing questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peak at [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) and [sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) That should have what you need to craft the appropriate query. I'm guessing something like this should get you started

```
SELECT
    DES.session_id
,   DES.host_name
,   DES.program_name
,   DES.client_interface_name
,   DES.login_name
,   DEC.client_net_address
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_connections AS DEC
    INNER JOIN
        sys.dm_exec_sessions AS DES
        ON DES.session_id = DEC.session_id  
WHERE
    DEC.client_net_address IS NOT NULL;
```